# Align text evenly css

Tags: css

I tried to look it up myself but having trouble wording it. So I made a badly photoshopped example of what I wanna try to do.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here's what I have now:

[image]

Here's what I want:

[image]

Notice the box moved slightly to accommodate the shorter name.

Current CSS:

```
.comment {
    background-color: #09F;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-right: 50px;

}
```

Current HTML(With parts of php :P):

```
echo "<br />" . $row['name']; ?> > <span class='comment'>
<?php echo $row['comment']; ?></span>
<span class='commentInfo'><--(<?php echo $properdate; ?>)</span><br/>
```

Comment: Provide the relevant parts of your current HTML & CSS.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Done :) Updated main post

Comment: The easiest solution would probably be to either make a `<table>` or put each column in a div

Comment: @asimes Never even thought of that! :O

Comment: What do you mean by “Notice the box moved slightly to accommodate the shorter name.”?

Comment: @Sunyatasattva, look at the position of "Love this!!" after "Laura"

Comment: add a default width to the name div. set the box-sizing to border-box;

Comment: You mean in the first example, right? My confusion came from the fact that in the second example “Love this!!” is also *slightly* misaligned. But I believe this might be just a mistake, right?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two choices

### Fixed-width `inline-block`s

Wrap the discrete parts of the conversation in HTML elements, use `display: inline-block` and give the ones you need a fixed-width.

It would look something like this

#### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li class="entry">
      <span class="name">Laura:</span>
      <span class="comment">Hey!</span>
      <span class="meta">&larr; (25/July/2013 5:43 PM)</span>
    </li>
    <li class="entry">
      <span class="name">Austen: </span>
      <span class="comment">Love this!!</span>
      <span class="meta">&larr; (25/July/2013 5:43 PM)</span>
    </li>
```

#### CSS

```
.entry .name {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
}
```

See a working example of this here: <kbd>[**Working example**](http://jsbin.com/inawom/1/)</kbd>

### Tables

I wouldn't recommend going the table approach, as tables should be used for tabular data, and not for layout. However, your content actually is kind of tabular, and it might make sense to use a table.

The table model will handle most of your problems for you.

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr class="entry">
      <td class="name">Laura:</td>
      <td class="comment">Hey!</td>
      <td class="meta">&larr; (25/July/2013 5:43 PM)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="entry">
      <td class="name">Austen: </td>
      <td class="comment">Love this!!</td>
      <td class="meta">&larr; (25/July/2013 5:43 PM)</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

And that's all you need. No special CSS.

<kbd>[**Working example 2**](http://jsbin.com/inawom/2/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

As another solution you could make use of the [display:table*;](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) properties in CSS for block elements.

By defining the containing div as a table-row and the span tags inside as table-cell:

```
div.table { display:table-row; }
div.table span { display:table-cell; }

<div class="table">
    <span>See</span>
    <span>Works</span>
</div>
```

See working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/TGUN3/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a css framework which is supporting grid system.
Below is an example made using twitter bootstrap.

Import the css:

```
@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="span12">
    <div class="span1">Austin</div>
    <div class="span1"> > </div>
    <div class="span7">Hey 25/July/2013 4:45PM</div>
</div>
<div class="span12">
    <div class="span1">Austin</div>
    <div class="span1"> > </div>
    <div class="span7">Hi 25/July/2013 4:59PM</div>
</div>
<div class="span12">
    <div class="span1">Laura</div>
    <div class="span1"> > </div>
    <div class="span7">Love this!! 25/July/2013 5:45PM</div>
</div>
<div class="span12">
    <div class="span1">Austin</div>
    <div class="span1"> > </div>
    <div class="span7">Rawr 25/July/2013 6:45PM</div>
</div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/6247/

You can modify the span size as you wish.

More information about bootstrap grid :

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/twitter-bootstrap-101-the-grid/